# How to link PHP table values with id to javascript using arrays?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, linegraph

Let me explain my question/task:

1) I have a PHP table showing temperature at a certain date and time, with API from a weather forecast.
2) Job is: translate this table into a line graph with Javascript.
3) I need to create a link between the PHP table and my Javascript code. But how do I do this using 'arrays'? 
4) My current method: using an id tag for each td row in the PHP table. Next, making a for loop which checks the PHP table 40 times (the number of datapoints I need for the chart), to collect the next td row (unfortunately I get 40 times the same value).

Shortly, how can I use the table data and make it 'available' in Javascript to create a line chart from as a visualt representation of the temperature.

Here under you can find my current coding in PHP and Javascript. 
Any feedback, help or advise is very welcom!
Thank you upfront!

PHP-part for loop:

```
echo "<table>";

for ($j=0; $j < 40 ; $j++) { 

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td id=Temp>{$data->list[$j]->main->temp}</td>";
    echo "<td id=Datum>{$data->list[$j]->dt_txt}</td";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Javascript:

```
var temp = new Array();
var datum = new Array();

for (var i=0; i < 40 ; i++) { 

   temp[i] = document.getElementById("Temp").innerText;
   datum[i] = document.getElementById("Datum").innerText;

}
```

Greetz,
C.

Answer (score 0):

IDs have to be unique, you can't have the same `id=Temp` and `id=Datum` on every row. You should use a class. Then you can loop over all the elements with the class.

PHP:

```
echo "<table>";

for ($j=0; $j < 40 ; $j++) { 

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class="Temp">{$data->list[$j]->main->temp}</td>";
    echo "<td class="Datum">{$data->list[$j]->dt_txt}</td";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

JS:

```
var temp = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".Temp")).map(el => el.innerText);
var datum = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".Datum")).map(el => el.innerText);
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your feedback but i get a error on the map function:                     
 Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...).map is not a function
    at script.js:12

Comment: Fixed it. The NodeList has to be converted to an array.

Comment: Many Thanks, I didn't have any errors now but for some reason my Array's are empty, i didn't get the 40 values in it.

Comment: Another stupid mistake, it should be `querySelectorAll`